# How can I set several breaks for different values in a plot in R?

Tags: r, image, plot, break

I have tried several options but I am not able to make it work, I would like to represent the values ​​of a matrix in a plot.

I am trying to have different values ​​represented by certain colors and the rest are represented by a gradual palette.

The correspondence between values ​​and colors is:

- Red: -2
- Green: -1
- Black: -0.7
- Blue: -0.5
- "YlOrRd" palette: 0-inf

This is the code I tried, I dont know what im doing wrong, but I only get to show all the values ​​with the heat palette.

```
y1<-c(-2,-1,-0.7,0.5,-2)
y2<-rep(-0.7,5)
y3<-seq(1,500,by=100)
y4<-rep(250,5)
y5<-seq(60,100,by=10)
heat<-rbind(y1,y2,y3,y4,y5)

bk = seq(-2, max(heat), length.out = 5)
color1 <- colorpanel(sum(bk[-1]<=-1.1), "red","red")
color2 <- colorpanel(sum(bk[-1]>-1.1 & bk[-1]<=-0.9), "green", "green") 
color3 <- colorpanel(sum(bk[-1]>-0.9 & bk[-1]<=-0.6), "black","black")
color4 <- colorpanel(sum(bk[-1]>-0.6 & bk[-1]<=-0.4), "blue", "blue")
color5 <- colorpanel(sum(bk[-1]>-0.4), "yellow","red")
colors <- c(color1,color2,color3,color4,color5)

image(t(apply(heat, 2, rev)),col=colors)
```

I would be very grateful if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `image()` if you hard-code all of the colors (perhaps there's a more elegant way that I don't know).

```
grad <- colorRampPalette(c("#ffffb2", "#fd8d3c", "#bd0026"))
cols <- grad(max(round(h5$val))+1)
cols_val <- rep(NA, length(heat$val))
cols_val[which(heat$val >=0)] <- cols[round(heat$val[which(heat$val >=0)])+1]
cols_val[which(heat$val == -2)] <- "red"
cols_val[which(heat$val == -1)] <- "green"
cols_val[which(heat$val == -.7)] <- "black"
cols_val[which(heat$val == -.5)] <- "blue"

brk <- c(-2.5, -1.5, -.75, -.25, seq(0,410, by=10))
image(t(heat), breaks=brk, col = c("red", "green", "black", "blue", grad(41)))
```

[image]

You could, however, do it slightly more elegantly with `ggplot()` [also, I assumed that you wanted the fourth element of `y1` to b -0.5]:

```
heat <- t(heat) %>% as_tibble %>% 
  mutate(obs = 1:n()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-obs, names_to="y", values_to="val") %>% 
  mutate(y = factor(y, levels=c("y1", "y2", "y3", "y4", "y5")) )
h1 <- heat %>% filter(val == -2)
h2 <- heat %>% filter(val == -1)
h3 <- heat %>% filter(val == -.7)
h4 <- heat %>% filter(val == -.5)
h5 <- heat %>% filter(val >= 0)

ggplot() + 
  geom_tile(data=h1, aes(x=obs, y=y), fill="red", width=1) + 
  geom_tile(data=h2, aes(x=obs, y=y), fill="green") + 
  geom_tile(data=h3, aes(x=obs, y=y), fill="black") + 
  geom_tile(data=h4, aes(x=obs, y=y), fill="blue") + 
  geom_tile(data=h5, aes(x=obs, y=y, fill=val)) + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors=c("#ffffb2", "#fd8d3c", "#bd0026")) + 
  geom_text(data=heat, aes(x=obs, y=y, label=val), col="gray60") + 
  theme_classic() + 
  labs(x="Observation", y="")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering! I've been a while trying to understand what "ht" was, this line was missing before applying mutate(): `ht <-heat`

Comment: @Cris_91 sorry, that was my sloppy coding - I had done the ggplot version before the image version, but didn't put the required data object above.  I edited the code to use `heat` instead of `ht`.